# Why can't I pass an argument into a toString() method and why does it give a null?

Tags: java, null, tostring

In the parent class, I have this:

```
public String toString(String employeetype) {
    return super.toString() + "\n" + employeetype + employeeno + " Hired on: "
    + DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(datehired) + " ";
}
```

and in the child classes, I have these two:

```
public String toString() {
    return super.toString("SalariedEmployee") + "[salary= " + this.pay() + "]";
}
public String toString() {
    return super.toString("HourlyEmployee") + "[salary= " + this.pay() + "]";
}
```

When I call them, they print out:

```
Person [name=John Doe, ssno=012345678, gender=Male]
SalariedEmployeenull Hired on: Feb 25, 2014 [salary= $0.0 Per Week]
Person [name=John Doe, ssno=012345678, gender=Male]
HourlyEmployeenull Hired on: Feb 25, 2014 [salary= $0.0 Per Hour from ]
```

So why does say SalariedEmployeenull and HourlyEmployeeNull instead of SalariedEmployee and HourlyEmployee? Is there a way to fix this while keeping the code in this format? If not, why can't I pass as an argument? I'd like to know how it works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Let's see you calling them. What are the values of the various fields?

Comment: "Why can't I pass an argument into a toString()" <-- well, you _can_ have .toString() with arguments; it just won't be the `.toString()` defined by `Object`. Note: you should add the `@Override` annotation to `.toString()` (without arguments)

Comment: I have no idea what `employeeno` is, but apparently it's `null`.  And the reason the `null` runs up right against `SalariedEmployee` and `HourlyEmployee` is that you forgot to add a space in between.

Answer (score 1):

> So why does say SalariedEmployeenull and HourlyEmployeeNull instead of SalariedEmployee and HourlyEmployee?

Because `employeeno` is `null`. And to make your output clearer, there should be a space between it and `employeetype`.

Why is `employeeno` null? We can't know until you give us some more information.

Comment: +1 for excellent choice of commenter to plagiarize from.  :) :) :)

Comment: I absolutely did not see your comment when I wrote this.

Comment: If you want me to delete this answer, I will.

Comment: I think you pre-cognitively plagiarized from me  ;)

Comment: No, I'm kidding.  I think we were typing at the same time.

Comment: I feel like such an idiot! It was null. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Original poster -- when an answer helps you, mark it as the answer to your question; since it was helpful, it is also normal to upvote it.

Comment: @user3353692: please consider accepting this as your answer, by clicking on the big green checkmark. Thanks!